# Z3 Java: simplify a distributive expression

Tags: java, z3

I need to simplify a distributive expression in Java with z3 theorem prover:

```
(simplify (or (and (<= b 0) (<= a 0)) (and (not (<= b 0)) (<= a 0))))
```

Usually the z3 prover should return the following expression:

```
(<= a 0)
```

But what I get is the same expression again:

```
(or (and (<= b 0) (<= a 0)) (and (not (<= b 0)) (<= a 0)))
```

Here is the java code:

```
Context ctx = new Context(configuration);

ArithExpr a = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("a"), ctx.getIntSort());
ArithExpr b = (ArithExpr) ctx.mkConst(ctx.mkSymbol("b"), ctx.getIntSort());
IntNum zero = this.context.mkInt(0);

Expr expr = ctx.mkOr(
    ctx.mkAnd(ctx.mkLe(a, zero), ctx.mkLe(b, zero)),
    ctx.mkAnd(ctx.mkLe(a, zero), ctx.mkGt(b, zero)));

expr = expr.simplify();
```

Am I missing something and what can I do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just curious: Is that `(b <= 0 && a <= 0) or ((!(b <= 0)) and (a <= 0))`?

Comment: Maybe `ctx.mkGt(b, zero)`, i.e. you changing !(b <= 0) to (b > 0) affects the simplification?

Comment: No, unfortunately this brings nothing.

Comment: What is with the method Expr.simplify(Params) instead of Expr.simplify(). Maybe this could help!? But I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to solve the problem. What I do is applying my expression with the tactic `ctx-solver-simplify`. This will display a resulting set of goals. In Java it looks like this:

```
Goal g = this.context.mkGoal(true, false, false);
g.add((BoolExpr) expr);

ApplyResult ar = this.context.mkTactic("ctx-solver-simplify").apply(g);
Goal[] subgoals = ar.getSubgoals();
BoolExpr[] formulas_0 = subgoals[0].getFormulas();
```

The array `formulas_0` contains the simplified expression.